# Редактирования и отправка данных js

Tags: php, javascript

форма Редактирования заказа мне нужно взять отредактированные поля и записать в базу. я сделал так

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#firstname').change(function () {
        var first = $('#firstname').val();
        var name = 'Изменено имя - ';
        var firstname = name+first;
        var order_id = $('#order_id').val();

        console.log(firstname);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/index.php?route=account/order/history_edit_order',
            data:{
                "action":firstname,
                "order_id":order_id
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#test').html(data);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Все работает, но получается если не нажать на кнопку сохранить, данные с формы не сохраняться,  а в историю данные запишутся. Подскажите может перед отправкой сделать проверку или есть другой способ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает по onchange записывать элементы в массив а по onSubmit формы - отправлять этот массив на сервер?

```js
var elements={};
$("#myform *[name]").change(function(){
  elements[this.name]=$(this).val();
});
$("#myform").submit(function(){
  console.log(elements);
  elements={};
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id = 'myform'>
  <input name='field1' /><br>
  <input name='field2' /><br>
  <input name='field3' /><br>
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо я в js не особо разбираюсь.